# xcode interface builder : nib is not being displayed while placing inside other nib

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, nib

[image]I have developed a `custom UIView` with `nib` file such that I can reuse it whenever needed. Now the thing is I have a `nib` of a `UIViewController` and I am drag and drop a Dummy UIView inside it and changing the `Class Name` to custom view's class name. This works fine when I run my application. I can see the Custom View in my screen on runtime. But I can not see it in Interface builder. So, my question is, is it possible to see the custom view's layout in view controller's nib through interface builder?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please add screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't provide such feature yet (at least not without 3rd party plugins which you can look for). Fortunately, it makes nibs processing much faster (performance-wise).

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a nib from inside another nib.

You could get around this by leaving the view in your view controller's nib as a placeholder, then loading the custom view's nib in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *customViewNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
    CustomView *customView = [[customViewNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]

    customView.frame = self.placeholderView.bounds;
    [self.placeholderView addSubView:customView];
}
```

Comment: It is not correct, you can load nibs from other nibs.

Comment: Not by just changing the class name of a `UIView`.